# ¿Cómo poner un poner tope numérico a un ID?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy creando una tabla en mi base de datos y necesito ponerle un tope a la cantidad de ID posibles. Quiero que como máximo hayan 5000 ID's

Esta es mi sentencia de creación de la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100)
)
```

¿Cómo puedo ponerle un máximo a mi campo Id?

Comment: Vas a limitar a 5000 el ingreso de registro a tu tabla  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear un `constraint` que impida agregar id's mas grandes que 5000 asi:

```
CREATE TABLE Empleados(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT Id_LessThan5000 
    CHECK (Id < 5000)
)
```